# Char Comparison in Common Lisp

Tags: sorting, char, comparison, lisp, common-lisp

How can i compare characters with Common Lisp?
I have google it and found out that there are some functions to do the comparison, like `char=`, `char/=`, `char<`, `char>`, `char<=`, and `char>=`. But, i can't use all of the functions just like:

```
(char= 'a 'a)  
(char< 'a 'b)
```

If i type those command, CLISP just give me the error message "Argument A is not a character". Why "A" is not a character?
I have to write like `(char= #\a #\a)` to make it working.
I want to make functions to did character sorting.

Thank you.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`A` is a symbol, not a character. The string functions will accept symbols and use the symbol's name, but the character functions only accept true character objects, which are entered using `#\` syntax. So you can do:

```
(string< 'a 'a)
(string< 'a 'b)
```

For reference:

- `#\a` => character
- `"a"` => string
- `a` => symbol